New poured concrete footing 1 inch low
I poured concrete a few days ago and once it cured, one of them sunk. How could I raise the concrete 1" higher? I have installed Simpson Strong Tie adjustable post for the beam to sit right to.
Edit: Sorry I had to correct the post. It’s actually 1” low


Did someone stand on the cardboard tube before it was filled, or has the actual footing sunk?

The footing sunk. It just looks like that because of the rain

if the footing is moving around like that it may not be suitable to attach your deck to.

Redo that footing on a suitable base.

If the footing sunk under its own  weight, it is not suitable to build anything on.   Since it looks like it is plumb and level, I suspect that it has not sunk, but was measured incorrectly.  (1 1/2 "  the thickness of most framing 2x lumber!  )Things rarely sink perfectly level.  You need to determine if it actually has sunken, or if there was a mistake made. That will determine which course of action is needed to correct the situation.

I’d love to hear more details about this footing: depth, diameter, whether the bottom of the hole was undisturbed ground, rainfall around the time of the pour… as mentioned, it’s extremely odd that it would sink so perfectly.

Thanks for the reply everyone. It’s 10 inch diameter that’s 3.5’ down and underneath is crushed stone. The rain happened following day.

Would helical plies help out if I shouldn’t use that base anymore?

I doubt the footing sank.  More likely, it wasn't at the right level to begin with.  I'm surprised you attached it to the joist hanger already.

It's pretty rare that deck piers come out at perfect height unless you have lasers set up and there's no settling whatsoever during the pour. It's too easy for forms to shift, etc., as you work. That's why there are almost always posts cut to precise length on top of them.
In this case, your "post" will simply be a bit of treated lumber--essentially an extension of the beam. Since it's so short, run the grain crossways (horizontal) to prevent splitting. Slim down a scrap of joist to 3½" by 3½" by 1" high and lay it in there. Put one small fastener into it so it doesn't get bumped out of position as you build.

Thank you. I used strings, originally I was going to use the laser.
I was actually thinking of doing that but using a composite deck that’s 1” instead. Either way if this would work then this would save me the headache..

You're welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

If you mean that you'll use decking for the post, be aware that composite decking isn't necessarily considered structural. Your inspector may not accept it.
